# How to get floats out of list one by one to calculate with them

Tags: python, list

I have list with float values, but I need to use them 1 by 1 and do some stuff with them. I want to use them, but I don't know how to get them out of list one by one.

```
    listthing = [7.0, 3.9, 5.25]
```

Now I need to use them in calculation

```
    lenghtstuff = float(listthing) * 100 * (7.0 * 2.0 + 0.5)
```

But I need to make calculation with each value from the list , and don't know how to do it so it would do 
        1) 7.0 * 100 * (7.0 * 2.0 + 0.5)
        2) 3.9 * 100 * (7.0 * 2.0 + 0.5) etc

Comment: It's unclear what calculation you want to make, so it's hard for us to tell you how to deal with the list.

Comment: I suggest you read any basic Python tutorial.

Comment: Surely if you've learned about lists you've learned how to do basic list indexing and how to iterate over lists... Which text book / tutorial are you learning Python from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutoring service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) loop.

```
for number in listthing:
    lenghtstuff = float(number) * 100 * (7.0 * 2.0 + 0.5)
    #do something with lengthstuff such as print it or append it to another list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map((lambda x: x* 100 * (7.0 * 2.0 + 0.5)), listthing))
```

I think what you're trying to use is a map.

Updated version with list comprehension:

```
[x* 100 * (7.0 * 2.0 + 0.5) for x in listthing]
```

Comment: You guys are right, I updated the answer. I guess that's what a weekend of Haskell does to you.

Comment: @PM2Ring Why only C-based? I think it's perfectly fine to use existing Python functions as well. And how does the list comp avoid the function call? Would you copy the code from inside the function?

Comment: @StefanPochmann What I mean is that if you're writing an expression as a function just to use it as the function arg for `map` then it doesn't matter whether the function is a proper `def` function or a `lambda`, you should just write the expression in a list comp. But I agree that my previous comment could be misleading, so I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is just converting your list of floats to a numpy array like so:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([7.0, 3.9, 5.25])
resulting_arr = arr * 100 * (7.0 * 2.0 + 0.5)
```

Numpy will perform the operations across the array by default; this is of course dependent on you having it installed, as it's not in the standard library.

Comment: Numpy may be overkill for something this simple, unless you're already using Numpy for something else (and given the OP's level of understanding I highly doubt that they're using Numpy at this stage). OTOH, your code does show that the kind of syntax the OP was attempting _is_ valid in the right circumstances.